# __next__ and next with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm writing an implementation of doubly linked lists. In order to traverse the list, I'm using something like:

```
class Node:
    """ A node in our linked list """
    def __init__(self, value: Any, next: Union['Node', None] =None,
            previous: Union['Node', None] =None) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
        self.previous = previous

    ...

    def __next__(self, direction: int =1) -> Union['Node', None]:
        if direction == 1:
            return self.get_next()
        else:
            return self.get_previous()

    ...
```

where `get_next` and `get_previous` are just getters of `self.next` and `self.previous`.

However, PyCharm yells at me for trying to call `next` as
`next(some_node, direction=-1)`. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can't just add arbitrary arguments to magic methods, you need to match the data model definition. If you want to offer an iterator the other way, that's [`__reversed__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides `__iter__` there is also `__reversed__`. Both are required to return `iterators`. The `__next__` method should be implemented on `iterators` (not on node-classes). Note that all magic methods (when called by a function like `next` instead of directly invoked) need to implement the **expected arguments** not more - not less.

For example a doubly linked list could just implement `__iter__` and `__reversed__` and rely on `next` and `previous` attribute of the Node:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val, nxt, prv):
        self.val = val
        self.nxt = nxt
        self.prv = prv


class DoublyLinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, base=None, last=None):
        self.base = base
        self.last = last

    def prepend(self, val):
        new = Node(val, self.base, None)
        if self.base is None:
            self.base = new
            self.last = new
        else:
            self.base.prv = new
            self.base = new

    def append(self, val):
        new = Node(val, None, self.last)
        if self.last is None:
            self.base = new
            self.last = new
        else:
            self.last.nxt = new
            self.last = new

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.base
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.nxt

    def __reversed__(self):
        current = self.last
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.prv
```

For example:

```
dl = DoublyLinkedList()
dl.prepend(10)
dl.prepend(20)
dl.prepend(30)

for i in dl:
    print(i.val)
```

gives:

```
30
20
10
```

similar for `reversed`:

```
for i in reversed(dl):
    print(i.val)

# prints:
10
20
30
```

Comment: Thank you, this was _really_ helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`__next__` is part of the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) and should be used as described in said protocol, doing otherwise only make problems with the rest python.

In your case just rename the function to simple `next` and use as `some_node.next(-1)`, though I would change the `direction` argument to a boolean, as that is how you use it, and its name too. Like this for example

```
class None: 
    ...

    def next(self, forward:bool=True) -> Union['Node', None]:
        if forward:
            return self.get_next()
        else:
            return self.get_previous()
```

and use as `some_node.next()`, `some_node.next(False)` or even `some_node.next(0)` (using 0 instead of False for the same effect)

Answer (score 1):

The extra argument to `next` is a default value, and `__next__` doesn't take any extra arguments. Python doesn't have any sort of two-way iterators. If your interface is not exactly the same as `for i in obj:`, then you should write your own.